# I want to calculate the number of days with no rainfall?

Tags: php, html

I created two arrays, one for the dates and for the rainfall. Now, I want to show the number of days with no rain (like when the user input 0 to indicate no rain). How could I do this? Thank you

PHP code I got so far:

```
$rainf_array = array($rainf0, $rainf1, $rainf2, $rainf3, $rainf4, $rainf5, $rainf6 ); 
$date_array = array($date0, $date1, $date2, $date3, $date4, $date5, $date6 );

//no rainfall 
    
sort($date_array);
echo "</br>The number of days with no rain was: ";
for ($i=0; $i< 1; $i++) 
{ 
 echo $date_array[$i]." ";
}
```

Comment: what are the values for $rainfX and $dateX?

Comment: they are the HTML form input variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done PHP for some years ^^

```
$days_with_rain = 0;
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($date_array); $i++){
   if(in_array($date_array[$i], $rainf_array)){
       $days_with_rain++;
   }
}
```

You can eat errors. Hope you get the idea. Just loop over the dates and check, if the date is in the rain array. That's it. If the date is in the rain array, count a counter up.